# I cannot run jQuery in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2017

I cannot run any jQuery or JavaScript in my code editor. I Googled many times but couldn’t find any answer.

[image: It says ReferenceError: $ is not defined]

Comment: jQuery is *frontend* library, why do you run it with *backend* Node.js?

Comment: @str at first jQuery is a JS framework, so it may be used in node too

Comment: and please do not post any pictures - post the error as text in this post. and describe also what you have tried so far. Also post the relevant code...

Comment: @messerbill jQuery is mainly to manipulate the DOM, but the backend does not have a DOM.

Comment: @str true that, but jQuery may also be used for a lot of other features

Comment: _“I cannot run any jQuery **or JavaScript** in my code editor”_ — it looks like you _can_ run plain JavaScript, or else there wouldn’t be a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @messerbill You mean for scrolling like in the question? Makes a lot of sense on the backend...

Comment: @str as one of many.... https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/ - and at least the topic is not about `does it make sense to use jquery in nodeJs`...

Comment: but you are right - i never used jQuery in the backend. But as i said...this is not the topic

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (g:\practice\rahulbhai\final_theare\theater.js:1:84)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3.


this my errors, and i am new to stackonerflow please kindly consider my ignorance.

Comment: @Xufox there is a reference error

Comment: @AsifAhmedOmi Yes. Again, this is a JavaScript error. If you couldn’t run JavaScript, there would not be such an error. This means that you can run JavaScript, contrary to what you said in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question is very low quality, I think what you're searching for is [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

Install it as a VSCode Extension, and you will be able to run Javascript code in the software with `F1` > `Run Code`. To stop: `F1` > `Stop Code Run`.

Concerning *jQuery*, this is a client library that manipulates DOM, I don't think you can run it into a console.

Comment: i installed it. but i cannot run it

Comment: i also cannot run it from console